# Azure devops react native ios build fails with generic error 65

Tags: react-native, azure-devops

My react native build is failing on iOS xcode build for mac...

Error on the pipeline:

```
▸ Check Dependencies
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
Check dependencies
(1 failure)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

How to know what dependencies are affected?

not on verbose, or system log I can see more info

Comment: How's your build definition or yaml file like? Could you share it? Which agent pool do you use? Do you have any error when you build locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, error 65 can indicate problems with the signing process. In some cases, this can be solved using the `manual` signing option. Provisioning profile id is required for manual signing.

```
signingOption: 'manual'
provisioningProfileUuid: ***
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?